# Application Load Balancer https request to EC2 nodejs running on port 3000

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have an ALB that is in HTTPS that will request to my EC2 instance.

I configured the ALB listeners to HTTP/HTTPS then target my EC2.

When I try to access my ALB with these:

1. `https://domainSample`
   *Response = Welcome to nginx*
2. `https://domainSample/api/getSample`
   *Response = 404 Not Found nginx*
3. `https://domainSample:3000`
   *No Response*

This is my nginx configuration in EC2 that runs on port 3000

```
 server {

            listen 80;
            server_name domainSample;

            location / {
                    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            }
  }
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have search and read about the documentation on AWS and do some tweek and test to the application.

What I understand in the flow of the request from the **ALB** to **EC2**.

In configuring the **ALB**, In Target Groups, we need to set the target of its request which will be the **EC2** that your application is running on to.

For instance, we have **Node js** running on to **port 3000** in the **EC2**.
We will add the target instance which **we specify the port on 3000**.

This solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: Congratulations.

Comment: @Richard - Can you please let more details to resolve this error? I am having same issue. Please help!!